# How can I mask a "get" URL and make it look look like a file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to first apologize for my choice of words. I haven't been in the web dev business to properly word the title, so there's that.

I'm using Apache Server and I have a .htaccess file in the root folder of my project. It specifies a 404 page and also a rewrite condition for removing the .php out of a file in the URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
</IfModule>
```

I have a users section on my page "social.php" and retrieve them using a GET variable in my code.

Example URL:

```
 www.mysite.com/users/social.php?username=someuser
```

However, I wanted to know how I could make it look something like:

```
 www.mysite.com/users/someuser
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Broad overview as I'm not familiar with PHP: use the same handler for everything matching `r'/users/([a-z]+)/?'` (or whatever matches your usernames), and that regex group is your username variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have your root .htaccess as this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^users/(\w+)/?$ /users/social.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't work! It broke everything in subdirectories. I can't access them as "www.site.com/options" for example.

Comment: How can a rule with pattern `user/\w+` break something with `/options`? You need to report your problem better I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is only partly a mod_rewrite problem at this point.

The first part is to route URLs like `/users/[a-z]+` to some script `/social.php`
`RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ social.php?username=$1`

The second part is inside social.php you need to get the username "someuser" in `$_GET['username']`.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your answer to perhaps include some code?